# Gradle not creating workable jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle, executable-jar

The Github repo is **https://github.com/jzheaux/terracotta-bank-spring**
and I want an executable jar file for this project so my steps are

1. `./gradlew bootJar`

jar gets created successfully inside build/libs

2. `cd build/libs`
3. `java -jar terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Spring starts successfully

4. But when I click on `localhost:8080`

I get the below error when
**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Oct 12 18:43:47 SGT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/index.jsp

Comment: This project uses war plugin. So it will build an war. Why do you need an jar? The war runs on tomcat without any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `spring-mvc` project with `.jsp` files. Jsp files are handled differently when run as a jar or inside a app server.

When you try to build the project with `./gradlew clean build` a `war` file will be generated. You can run the war as a standalone server because it has embedded tomcat as a dependency. Just run

```
cd /build/libs
java -jar terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

Then go to `http://localhost:8080`

[image: Terracotta Homepage]

Comment: Still getting the same error. 
**Whitelabel Error Page**
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Oct 13 17:36:49 SGT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/index.jsp

My application.properties is
```spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password

mailjet.api.key=key
mailjet.api.secret=secret

spring.mvc.view.prefix= /
spring.mvc.view.suffix= .jsp```

Comment: I have to use the jar as a standalone thing. So I went inside <br>```build/libs and ran 
java -jar terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ```.  Spring start is successful but on trying to access http://localhost:8080. that index.jsp error appears. So does it mean that standalone jar cannot be made out of this project?

Comment: Did you clean before running ? I have again tested with this properties and I had no problem getting to homepage. I tried ./gradlew clean bootJar and  java -jar build/libs/terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. I am adding homepage screenshot in the answer.

Comment: yes that's the thing..If you go inside build/libs and then run ```java -jar terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar``` you will get the problem. But if I try ```java -jar build/libs/terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar``` it works fine. My requirement is to use the jar as a standalone.Otherwise I have to checkout the code and then set the project directory the way it is in github and then run ```java -jar terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar```. 
In a nutshell, the jar cannot be run outside the project context. Let me know if you are u able to run it by keeping it in any folder

Comment: Let me know if you are able to take the jar and can run it by keeping inside a separate folder outside of the project.

Comment: I tried copying over build/. src/. and terracotta.png and placed it inside a separate folder and then I tried ```java -jar build/libs/terracotta-bank-spring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ``` and it works as expected. So need to zip the three things (build,src and terracotta.png)  and send it, instead of just using the jar file.Is that the correct approach?

Comment: Then the packaging will not be portable. I have edited the answer, I have found a workaround , not a very good solution. But it should work for you.

Comment: If it solves your problem, then please mark the answer as right answer.